# Jquery Move Single Element at a time

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Any Idea about this, In blog page there are list of blogs and in each blog there's image,title of blog,summary content and etc. The design of blog is image,title,contents and meta. I need to move the title upward of image, so I used the insertBefore. My is problem  all the title in the blogs are move upwards, so in each single blog there are tons of a blog title because I use insert. Any way to prevent it to capture all the title?

```
jQuery( ".bd-blog-header h2" ).insertBefore( ".bd-post-image" );
```

I also tried this

```
jQuery( ".blog-list" ).each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).find(".bd-post-image").append(jQuery(this).find(".bd-blog-header h2"))
});
```

This is a sample

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="img"></div>
     <div class="body">
         <h2>title</h2>
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
     <div class="img"></div>
     <div class="body">
         <h2>title</h2>
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
```

I want is two put the h2 upwards of the img, but what's happens is like this

```
<div class="container">
     <h2>title</h2>
     <h2>title</h2>
     <div class="img"></div>
     <div class="body">
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <h2>title</h2>
     <h2>title</h2>
     <div class="img"></div>
     <div class="body">
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
```

what I want is like this

```
<div class="container">
     <h2>title</h2>
     <div class="img"></div>
     <div class="body">
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <h2>title</h2>
     <div class="img"></div>
     <div class="body">
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well based on your code it would seem you're creating these blog listings with jquery so I don't see why you wouldn't insert the title first, then the image? That would avoid you having to `insertBefore`. Otherwise, you need a way to target the specific blog you want to move the title of.. and to do that you need something unique on each blog like an `ID`

Comment: it is not a custom built, I built in wordpress @AshleyBrown

Comment: You need to improve your explanation, are you moving the title upward the image on some particular event (example: on click, on hover)? Note that the jquery selector you are using, will match all **h2** tags that are inside an element with class **bd-blog-header**. If you want help, please add more code, html markup, etc, so we can see the context too.

Comment: @MisamidFloride Then I would first recommend just editing the template to change the order. with that said, D. Smania has made an excellent point and it basically continues on from my last remark... do you have a particular blog on the page you want to move the title of upwards? If so you'll need a unique identifier to target it other wise by using a specific css style selector e.g. psudeo `nth-child()`

Comment: @D.Smania just need to move it upward, because in the design I have it is should be title,image then content. I'm still searching it in google how to solve this one. The only code I have right now is that and yes I know it will select all the h2 and move it upward, I just can't figure out that it will move one element when you have a repeating container :D

Comment: @AshleyBrown I can't use a child for this one because all of them need to move upward :(
and also it is a plugin, because the default one doesn't have some feature that I need, but this plugin have  that features the only problem is the design, so I'm thinking to use jQuery to move the elements

Comment: @MisamidFloride But you said in your initial post `My is problem all the title in the blogs are move upwards` and now you say `all of them need to move upward`. You're not making sense here in what you actually want...

Comment: @AshleyBrown all of the title should be move upward

Comment: But your initial question says the problem **IS** that they **ALL** move upward? What is the actual problem here? Do they or don't they all move up? Do any at all move up?

Comment: Try to add the html markup of the anidated structure you have, but my guess is you need something like this: `$( ".bd-blog-header" ).find("h2").first().insertBefore( ".bd-post-image" );` or in a more simplified way: `$( ".bd-blog-header h2:first-child" ).insertBefore( ".bd-post-image" );`

Comment: I will try to create a scenerio wait

Comment: edited @AshleyBrown and D. Smania

Comment: already solve it

Comment: you say you solved it 3 minutes after I post my answer... curious that.

Comment: sorry didn't saw your post :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the parent element of each post, then loop through them. On each iteration find the h2 within it, then move up above the image that's also within the parent you selected.

```js
$('.container').each(function(index, element) {
 $(this).find('h2').insertBefore($(this).find('.img'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="img">image here</div>
     <div class="body">
         <h2>title</h2>
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
     <div class="img">image here</div>
     <div class="body">
         <h2>title</h2>
         <p>sample</p>
     </div>
     <div class="meta"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the future reference

```
jQuery( ".container" ).each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).find(".img").prepend(jQuery(this).find("h2"))
});
```